# React: Good Practices For CDNs, Node_Modules and Both

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cdn, node-modules

Been building a React application on top of [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which uses Webpack through react-scripts and has React/Redux/React-dom, etc. as dependencies in our package.json.

To use those JS dependencies, we use import statements, however, for other JS dependencies (i.e. the JS used in Bootstrap and jQuery), we import those through CDN.  (We have the Bootstrap CSS files in our CSS directory, and use import statements).

**Is there a generally accepted practice to use CDNs vs node_modules or both on the front-end side?**

My initial thought was to use CDNs to get static JS files if you're not going to use them as imports in your JS files, but wondered if that was the right way to think about it.

Obviously this isn't a React specific question, just using React to give more context.

Comment: You should serve your own versions since you're making your page's availability dependent on the CDNs being up/not changing. It will also need multiple requests to get all the code so the load time will usually be longer.

Comment: that definitely makes sense, was curious if there was a specific advantage to CDNs versus serving your own, as many sites still use CDNs

Comment: @Thiatt Not correct. Bootstrap and Jquery are most probably already cached in the browser and also from different domain assets can be downloaded in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I generally do:

(1) Setup `webpack.config.js` to assume global `React` and `ReactDOM` variables are available, to prevent them from being transpiled, minified, and bundled on every build. You can still use import statements in your files, as before, but the libraries will not be in your final bundle:

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}
```

(2) Use a CDN like http://www.jsdelivr.com/, which allows you to get multiple scripts as a single concatenated string, in a single request. This will minimize loading time.

(3) (Optional) Install React and ReactDOM as deps, and have the build process copy the minified js files from `node_modules/react(-dom)/dist` to your project's public files directory, and then create simple checks for the variables at the foot of the page, to inject includes pointing to your server, if the CDN calls happen to fail. For example:

```
if (!window.React) {
   $('head').append('<script src="/js/react.min.js">')
}
```